# Can't use select input x-editable on jQueryUI Dialog with Firefox

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, x-editable

I have a x-editable select input on a jQueryUI dialog.  When clicked, however, it doesn't allow it to be changed when rendered with Firefox (yet works with Chrome and IE).  If you close the dialog, I have another one not on a dialog, and it works perfect.  I am thinking it might be CSS z-access related, but am not sure.  How can I use a select input x-editable on a jQueryUI Dialog with Firefox?

http://jsbin.com/wesategigu/edit?html,output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Testing</title>  
        <link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.1/jqueryui-editable/css/jqueryui-editable.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.1/jqueryui-editable/js/jqueryui-editable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            $(function(){
                $("#dialog").dialog({
                    modal       : true,
                    open        : function() {
                        $('#status').editable({
                            value: 2,    
                            source: [
                                {value: 1, text: 'Active'},
                                {value: 2, text: 'Blocked'},
                                {value: 3, text: 'Deleted'}
                            ]
                        });
                    }
                });
                $('#status2').editable({
                    value: 2,    
                    source: [
                        {value: 1, text: 'Active'},
                        {value: 2, text: 'Blocked'},
                        {value: 3, text: 'Deleted'}
                    ]
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="dialog">
            <a href="#" id="status" data-type="select" data-pk="1" data-url="/post" data-title="Select status"></a>
        </div>
        <a href="#" id="status2" data-type="select" data-pk="1" data-url="/post" data-title="Select status"></a>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: It works perfectly for me. What browser do You use?

Comment: @BogdanKuštan  Firefox.  I've since tested on Chrome and IE, and they both are okay.

Comment: That's really strange behavior. `.ui-dialog` hijack click event (?), if You remone `.ui-dialog` flom modal window it works fine. Sorry at the moment I don't have a lot of time to play around. Will try to investigate more in the evening.

Comment: @BogdanKuštan  Yes it is strange!  Think it is CSS related?

Comment: I don't really know. This has something to do with modal dialog. I guess that when jquery creates modal dialog, it hijacks all events going outside ui-dialog element.

Comment: @BogdanKuštan  Hijack what?  It is just a select menu, and I wouldn't thin JS is even used to display the options.  Very odd!